# How to locate and access named ranges (global, nd per-worksheet) using xlrd, Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, named-ranges

The documentation for `xlrd` here
http://www.python-excel.org/
mentions that it is now possible in latest version, but does not say how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are actually reading; xlrd access to named ranges has been available for some years now (in version 0.6.0; latest version is 0.7.1) and came with full documentation ab initio.

[This is the xlrd documentation link](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html) that's given on the http://www.python-excel.org/ page that you mentioned. Hit PageDown twice and you should see a section headed *Named references, constants, formulas, and macros*. This gives an overview and points you to documentation of the `Book.name_*` methods & the `Name` object, and to a demonstration script.

Note that this is the SVN trunk version of the documentation and applies to a future release; it may mention one extra convenience method that's not available in the current released version of xlrd (which you can get from [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)) and which includes the relevant documentation file.

**Update** in response to """I got this far: someRange = book.name_map[u'somerange'][0] and now I want to iterate over it, grab values, get its dimensions, etc. Now what do I do? I tried dir(someRange) and help(someRange)  and it has not helped much."""

What you are calling `someRange` is an instance of the `Name` class. You need to read the [documentation of that class](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#__init__.Name-class). It would help if you were to read [the demonstration script xlrdnameAPIdemo.py](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/examples/xlrdnameAPIdemo.py) and try running it over your xls file(s). Note that "get its dimensions" logically precedes "iterate over it, grab values"; the convenience method `Name.area2d` may be what you need.

Comment: Ok John, so I got this far: `someRange = book.name_map[u'somerange'][0]` and now I want to iterate over it, grab values, get its dimensions, etc. Now what do I do? I tried `dir(someRange)` and `help(someRange)` and it has not helped much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial and it worked in my case only on XLS no XLSX (probably because on my XLSX `name.evaluated == 0`):

```
name = book.name_map['my_named_range'][0]
assert name.result.kind == xlrd.oREF
ref3d = name.result.value[0]
for sheet_index in range(ref3d.shtxlo, ref3d.shtxhi):
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
    for row in range(ref3d.rowxlo, min(ref3d.rowxhi, sheet.nrows)):
        for col in range(ref3d.colxlo, min(ref3d.colxhi, sheet.ncols)):
            cell = sheet.cell(row, col)
            # TODO: Do something with that cell.
```

You want to limit the number of columns and rows in the sheet in case your range is like `A:A` or `1:1` (i.e., the entire row or column).